# Capturing TM in Regex python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to capture Queen's University in the below. 
I tried using unidecode to standardize the encoding. 
But the pattern below is not capturing. Would appreciate your help!

```
from unidecode import unidecode
CV2 = unidecode(CV)

namepat = r'\d+\s+[A-Za-z&.(),:+# -]{5,150}?(?=[A-Z][A-Z])'
```

Ideally I would be capturing:

```
128 Queen(tm)s University#
```

Original CV

> 21 Iowa State University & Foundation IA 673,515 604,897 11.3 122
>   Wesleyan University CT 669,593 600,529 11.5 123 Cooper Union NY
>   668,408 641,324 4.2 124 Rochester Institute of Technology NY 668,406
>   627,786 6.5 125 Bucknell University PA 666,562 599,216 11.2 126
>   University of Massachusetts Foundation, Inc. MA 664,240 565,020 17.5
>   127 Virginia Tech Foundation VA 660,340 594,776 11.0 128 Queen\u2122s
>   University# ON 658,896 595,652 10.6 129 Colby College ME 649,992
>   599,557 8.4 130 Loma Linda University CA 648,490 597,669 8.5 131
>   Principia Corporation MO 638,419 593,054 7.6 132 College of the Holy
>   Cross MA 634,912 589,769 7.7 133 Mount Holyoke College MA 631,950
>   582,623 8.5 134 Oklahoma State Regents for Higher Education OK 625,719
>   447,538 39.8 135 Rensselaer Polytechnic Institute NY 616,836 583,350
>   5.7 136 Northeastern University MA 616,618 566,767 8.8 137 McMaster U

Output after CV2

> Wesleyan University CT 669,593 600,529 11.5 123 Cooper Union NY
>   668,408 641,324 4.2 124 Rochester Institute of Technology NY 668,406
>   627,786 6.5 125 Bucknell University PA 666,562 599,216 11.2 126
>   University of Massachusetts Foundation, Inc. MA 664,240 565,020 17.5
>   127 Virginia Tech Foundation VA 660,340 594,776 11.0 128 Queen(tm)s
>   University# ON 658,896 595,652 10.6 129 Colby College ME 649,992
>   599,557 8.4 130 Loma Linda University CA 648,490 597,669 8.5 131
>   Principia Corporation MO 638,419 593,054 7.6 132 College of the Holy
>   Cross MA 634,912 589,769 7.7 133 Mount Holyoke College MA 631,950
>   582,623 8.5 134 Oklahoma State Regents for Higher Education OK 625,719
>   447,538 39.8 135 Rensselaer Polytechnic Institute NY 616,836 583,350
>   5.7 136 Northeastern University M

Comment: You seriously have the text in one long chunk like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works.

```
print re.findall(namepat, CV2)

['123 Cooper Union ',
 '124 Rochester Institute of Technology ',
 '125 Bucknell University ',
 '126 University of Massachusetts Foundation, Inc. ',
 '127 Virginia Tech Foundation ',
 '128 Queen(tm)s University# ',
 '129 Colby College ',
 '130 Loma Linda University ',
 '131 Principia Corporation ',
 '132 College of the Holy Cross ',
 '133 Mount Holyoke College ',
 '134 Oklahoma State Regents for Higher Education ',
 '135 Rensselaer Polytechnic Institute ']
```

It might be nice to get rid of the trailing space.

```
namepat = r'\d+\s+[A-Za-z&.(),:+# -]{5,150}?(?= ?[A-Z][A-Z])'
```

Comment: Thanks! I realized I had made a really stupid naming error. This post helped me catch that.